# if I pass a file as positional parameter, bash complain when I put it in a variable

Tags: bash

This is quite peculiar: I have a function that takes a file path, read the last line and return the value.

Now, I would like to call this function from another script; so I just pass the path to the file, and get $1 in the function, so I can use it.

But it seems that for some reason, bash do not like the idea of me assigning $1 to a variable.

```
printval(){

textfile=$1

result=$(tail -n 1 $textfile)
echo $result
```

When I call the function:

```
printval "/User/admin/test.txt"
```

Now, no matter how do I pass the file path (I can pass it trough a variable or just as string), and no matter if I use $1 in the function, or if I type explicitly the path to the file, the result is that I get an error saying "permission denied.

Strange enough, if I do in the function

```
printval(){

result=$(tail -n 1 "/User/admin/test.txt")
echo $result
```

I don't get any error, and the file is read correctly.

What am I doing wrong? I simply want to pass a path to a file to the function, so I can use the content of that file in the function.

Comment: Your function works for me. `printval /User/admin/test.txt` as well as `printval "/User/admin/test.txt"`. Are you sure, that you test it with the same, accesible file? I'm using GNU bash 4.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: Can you copy-paste the entire, exact error you get? "permission denied" is not enough, you should include everything such as `tail: cannot open \`/User/admin/test.txt' for reading: Permission denied`

Comment: Thanks; yes, I am using a file that I just wrote in another function; the script analyze some data, write this text file, then I wrote the second function that grab the last few entry of the file and compare them; so if the file is accessible when writing, and the script is running in the same thread, with the same permissions, I don't see why it would give me the error.

Strange enough; I've moved the function on the top of the script and now it works just fine; also I was able to make it work using $1 directly, instead than copying it into a variable...makes no sense. I am on OSX btw

Answer (score 3):

Does the actual file you are using have a space in its filename? That is, are you actually typing something like this:

```
printval "/User/j doe/test.txt"
```

You should write your function with defensive quoting:

```
printval(){
  textfile=$1
  result=$(tail -n 1 "$textfile")
  echo "$result"
}
```

Quoting does not survive parameter passing. You can set `textfile` to `/User/j doe/test.txt` with `textfile=$1`, but when you use it, bash will expand `tail -n 1 $textfile` to `tail -n 1 /User/j doe/test.txt`, which references two file which probably don't exist. You need to quote the use of `$textfile` to avoid that (`tail -n 1 "$textfile"`).

Comment: The file do not have any special character or space; I tried to be defensive with file names, so I avoid weird names. Using $1 works thou, which I don't understand why wouldn't work saving it into a variable.

Comment: +1 Also, both the variables `textfile` and `result` in the function are completely redundant; you could simply use `printval() { tail -n 1 "$1" ; }`

Answer (score -2):

Call instead

```
printval /User/admin/test.txt
```

otherwise it fails (I'm not sure if the file it is looking for is "/User/admin/test.txt", I think not, but it fails)

put this on a .sh file

```
#!/bin/bash

printval(){

textfile=$1

result=$(tail -n 1 "$textfile")
echo $result
}

printval ~/.bashrc
```

and try it yourself. If instead of the last line, you use

```
printval "~/.bashrc"
```

it will complain as you say in your post.

Comment: Have you tested this? I don't believe the quotes make a difference.

Comment: Yes, I did test it. Try it yourself.

Comment: I don't know how you tested, but the quotes don't make a difference in this case.

Comment: With that edit, the quotes do make a difference because they suppress tilde-expansion.